# OpenCL for GPU vs. FPGA

Tags: cuda, opencl, fpga

I read recently about OpenCL/CUDA for FPGA vs. GPU
As I understood FPGA wins in power criteria.
The explanation for that ,I`ve found in some article:

> Reconfigurable devices can have much lower power consumption from peak
>   values since only configured portions of the chip are active

Based on said above I have a question - does it mean that ,if some CU [Compute Unit] doen`t execute any work-item,it still consumes power? (and if yes - what for it consumes power?)

Comment: FPGA Acceration cards are big and need a full workstation to plug into.... if you only have a few cards and its plugged into a workstation... what difference does it make about power?  power is what you worry about if its a portable device like a tablet or cellphone that run on batteries...to gain any advantage with power with an FPGA requires custom boards that integrate CPU and FPGA onto the same board...

Comment: These days, the Achilles' heel of FPGAs over a customer IC designs such as a GPU's, is that FPGA clock rates haven't improved in years... they still don't run much better than 200 Mhz for internal logic...verse 2-3 Ghz for a GPU... there are some that try to quote the serdes core speeds as the FPGA speeds, but those are just Pieces of a custom IC's glued inside of an FPGA and don't represent the real internal speed when performing Multiply-accumulates...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, idle circuitry still consumes power. It doesn't consume as much, but it still consumes some. The reason for this is down to how transistors work, and how CMOS logic gates consume power.

Classically, CMOS logic (the type on all modern chips) only consumes power when it switches state. This made is very low power when compared to the technologies that came before it which consumed power all the time. Even so, every time a clock edge occurs, some logic changes state even if there's no work to do. The higher the clock rate, the more power used. GPUs tend to have high clock rates so they can do lots of work; FPGAs tend to have low clock rates. That's the first effect, but it can be mitigated by not clocking circuits that have no work to do (called 'clock gating')

As the size of transistors became smaller and smaller, the amount of power used when switching became smaller, but other effects (known as leakage) became more significant. Now we're at a point where the leakage power is very significant, and it's multiplied up by the number of gates you have in a design. Complex designs have high leakage power; Simple designs have low leakage power (in very basic terms). This is a second effect.

Hence, for a simple task it may be more power efficient to have a small dedicated low speed FPGA rather than a large complex, but high speed / general purpose CPU/GPU.

Answer (score 3):

As always, it depends on the workload.  For workloads that are well-supported by native GPU hardware (e.g. floating point, texture filtering), I doubt an FPGA can compete.  Anecdotally, I've heard about image processing workloads where FPGAs are competitive or better.  That makes sense, since GPUs are not optimized to operate on small integers.  (For that reason, GPUs often are uncompetitive with CPUs running SSE2-optimized image processing code.)

As for power consumption, for GPUs, suitable workloads generally keep all the execution units busy, so it's a bit of an all-or-nothing proposition.

Comment: "GPUs are not optimized to operate on small integers.  (For that reason, GPUs often are uncompetitive with CPUs running SSE2-optimized image processing code.)". You realise that GPUs came from graphics processing and still contain logic to gear them for that kind of work.

Comment: Paul, the native 8-bit integer support built into the frame buffer hardware does not figure into general-purpose computations (not even image processing ones).  If you focus on the SMs' integer math capabilities, note that SSE2 can perform 16 8-bit integer operations in a single instruction, at a clock rate that is 5-6x higher than that of a GPU.  GPUs' higher core count cannot compensate for the difference.

For a specific example of such a workload, consider 3x3 median.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research on FPGAs and the way they work, these devices can be designed to be very power efficient and really fine-tuned for one special task (e.g., an algorithm) and use the smallest resources possible (therefore the lower amount of energy consumption among all possible choices except ASIC)

When implementing turning-complete algorithms using FPGAs, the designers have the option of either unrolling their algorithms to use the maximum parallelism offered or use a compact sequential design. Each method has its own cost-benefits; the former helps maximizing performance at the cost of higher resource consumption, and the latter helps minimizing area and resource consumption by reusing hardware at the cost of minimizing the performance.

This level of control over implementation of algorithms doesn’t exist when developing for GPUs. The developers have the control to use the most efficient algorithms yet they are not the one determining the final precise hardware implementation of their algorithms. Unlike FPGA designers who even count “nano-seconds” when calculating their design’s hardware implementation (using post-layout tools), GPU developers rely on available frameworks to enhance all implementation details for them automatically. They develop at much higher levels compared to FPGA designers.

So the well known topic of trade-offs pops up here too; you want exact control over the hardware implementation at the cost of longer development times? Choose FPGAs. You want parallelism, yet have made up your mind to give up exact control over hardware implementation and want to  develop using your existing software skills? use OpenCL.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @hamzed, but OpenCL is not taking control away from the designer of OpenCL on FPGAs. It actually gives the best of the both worlds: full programmability of FPGA with all custom parallel algorithm benefits as well as much better design closure speed vs. RTL. By being clever about your algorithm moving and not moving data you can get to near theoretical performance of FPGAs. Please see the last chart in this reference: https://www.iwocl.org/wp-content/uploads/iwocl2017-andrew-ling-fpga-sdk.pdf